# Groovy: how to apply filters using closure variable and NOT to a collection?

Tags: filter, groovy, closures

Groovy: how to apply filters using defined closure to a collection? e.g.

```
def f = { it -> it.name.contains("foo") }

aCollection.filter { it -> !it.name.contains("foo") }
```

How to apply the closure variable to the filter method? like

```
aCollection.filter {! f }  //NOT
```

Comment: What is the type of aCollection? What is the signature of filter?  You can pass f as parameter: aCollection.filter(f). If you want to negate the result of f: aCollection.filter{ !f(it) }

Comment: thanks. Just figured it out, calling closure is similar to calling method.